# GameObject in Unity wont reappear after it has been set to false by SetActive(false) in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to create a canvas that appears and disappears when P is pressed. I use the setActive(bool) method.
But when I hide the object in void start() it wont reappear with setActive(). If i dont hide the object in void start() everything wotks somehow as it should.
How can i get the canvas to hide at start and show up when P is pressed?`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameOverScreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] pauseObjects;
    public static bool isPaused = false;



    void Start()
    {
         Time.timeScale = 1;
        pauseObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("game-over");
        hidePaused();
       
        

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
       

        //uses the p button to pause and unpause the game
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
            
        {
            
            if (Time.timeScale == 1)
            { 
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                showPaused();
                isPaused = !isPaused;
               
                Debug.Log("d");
               
            }
            else if (Time.timeScale == 0)
            { 
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                hidePaused();
                isPaused = !isPaused;
                
                 Debug.Log("high");
            }
        }
    }
    public void showPaused()
    {
       
        Debug.Log("Succesfull");
        foreach (GameObject g in pauseObjects)
        {
            g.SetActive(true); 
            g.name = "ray";
        }
        isPaused = true;
       
        

    }

    //hides objects with ShowOnPause tag
    public void hidePaused()
    {
        
        foreach (GameObject g in pauseObjects)
        {
            g.SetActive(false);
           
        }
       
       
       
    }
```

Already mentioned above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution for this type of scenario: you could just create a public list of the gameObjects (adding them to it in inspector), and then manually deactivate the objects (just select them all at once and deactivate in inspector).

Then when you run the game:

1. They will all be deactivated - as you wanted.
2. You have a reference of them since you assigned already in inspector, so you can reactivate.
3. You won't have to use the FindGameObjects method (which can be quite taxing if you used often).

Simply change `public GameObject[] pauseObjects;` to `public List<GameObject> pauseObjects = new List<GameObject>();`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a little while since I used unity, if you deactivate the object that the script is attached to, you can't call any code from the script, because it will also deactivate every component attached to the object.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

You can attach the script to a parent object and add the canvas as a child.By doing so you can call SetActive on the canvas without affecting the parent object. Transform.GetChild() is one way of getting the objects attached to the parent.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html